# In document class elsarticle , double col why reference number are not visible in pdf but in single col?

Tags: two-column, elsarticle

I m using class elsarticle double col as below

```
\documentclass[final, 5p, times, authoryear, twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} % (For authoryear Elsevier citations)

% The bibliography file

\bibliography{ref_els}


\end{document}
```

then the reference numbers aren't visible but when I use single col as

```
\documentclass[times]{elsarticle}

    
the reference number are visible, why so?
```

Also the numbers are in order as usually happen in jebref.
plz guide where I am wrong.

regards

Answer (score 1):

The numbers appear after doing `bibtex + pdflatex + pdflatex`.

Using `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}`

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}    

\begin{filecontents}{mainrefs.bib}
    @article{einstein,
        author="Albert Einstein",
        title="{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Korper}",
        journal="Annalen der Physik",
        volume="322",
        number="10",
        pages="891--921",
        year="1905",
        DOI ="http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
        keywords="physics"
    }
    
    @book{dirac,
        title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
        author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
        isbn={9780198520115},
        series={International series of monographs on physics},
        year={1981},
        publisher={Clarendon Press},
        keywords = {physics}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\journal{Nuclear Physics B}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{}

\author{}

\begin{abstract}
Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a posteriori.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Space \sep  Time
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

The history starts with \cite{einstein} and continues with   \cite{dirac}.
 
\kant[1-3]

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

%\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}% ordered numbers <<<<<<

\bibliography{mainrefs}

\end{document}
```

Or use instead `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}` for ordered numbers.

[image: b]

Comment: I have tried both of these styles, in double col none of them is working.  Only reference head is appearing despite of numbers. Plz guide further

Comment: @KRISHNA CHAUHAN Did you try the code from my answer and compile the file several times after running bibtex?  `bibtex.exe filename.tex` must be run from the command prompt or usually from the tex editor.

Comment: I am using jebref for preparaing refrence file. Is it okay? Its working in single col :( but not in double col.

Comment: @KRISHNA CHAUHAN I do not know. Please add a sample of some of the generated references to your question.

Comment: plz guide me how add code here as its mixed lines , you will have difficulty in reading then

Comment: @KRISHNA CHAUHAN Try and I will see.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot @simon for your patience listening. actually previously I was using .............\documentclass[final, 5p, times,  authoryear, twocolumn]{elsarticle} and now .........\documentclass[final, 5p, times, twocolumn]{elsarticle}, that solved the number problem with references but do you plz help me with this numbering issue. I remember in IEEEtrans class the ref numbers are automatically adjusted as they appear in paper but here it follows the order from jebref file. Is there any solution for this. Regards

Comment: @KRISHNA CHAUHAN  Use `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}` for ordered numbers instead of `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}`

Comment: Thats solved already, Thanks:)